# Jest test suite failed to run because of "TypeError: Cannot read property 'xxx' of undefined"

Tags: typescript, jestjs, es6-module-loader

I am trying to reorganize the import/export statements of my TypeScript React project to make them shorter and cleaner, basically by the approach of defining an `index.ts` file in each feature specific folder to export resources (interface/type/function etc.) of that feature. This [Smarter way to organize "imports" blog](https://medium.com/@balramchavan/smarter-way-to-organize-import-statements-using-index-ts-file-s-in-angular-c685e9d645b7) explains almost the same idea.

But suddenly jest execution breaks with below stack trace after the changes. The entities involved have been spoofed for confidentiality purpose.

```sh
Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'FooBarEnum' of undefined



      at Object.FooBarEnum (src/features/Zoo/index.ts:93:23)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/features/CarPark/CarParkManager.ts:18:4)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/features/CarPark/index.ts:1:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/features/Zoo/ZooManager.ts:1:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/features/Zoo/index.ts:14:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/features/Rabbit/Rabbit.ts:4:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (test/features/Rabbit/Rabbit.test.ts:2:1)
```

Basically there is an enum defined in a constant file which can't be read at all.

I am pretty sure my jest setup is correct because it was executing successfully before this. And I use `babel-jest` and `@babel/preset-typescript` to compile.

Appreciate if someone can point me to a path for debugging as the stack trace doesn't really tell much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally I realized this is caused by a hidden circular dependency in my code base.

[TL;DR] Dependency cycle: `Rabbit` > `Zoo` index > `CarPark` index > `Zoo` index.

[Details] The situation is that `ZooManager` is exported from the index file of `Zoo` folder, and `ZooManager` imports `CarParkManager` which is exported from the index file of `CarPark` folder. 'FooBarEnum' is exported from the index file of `Zoo` folder and is used by `CarParkManager`, and that constitutes the dependency cycle.

I know the given spoofed example isn't really nice to read upon but this provides a hint that when you encounter similar issues, keep an eye on circular dependencies.

The [import/no-cycle](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/no-cycle.md) ESLint rule can be added to carry out a static check.

And the [madge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/madge) developer tool can be used to construct a visual module dependency graph.

References:

- [jest-type-error-cannot-read-property-default-of-undefined](https://www.karltarvas.com/2020/03/19/jest-type-error-cannot-read-property-default-of-undefined.html)
- [How to fix nasty circular dependencies in JavaScript & TypeScript](https://medium.com/visual-development/how-to-fix-nasty-circular-dependency-issues-once-and-for-all-in-javascript-typescript-a04c987cf0de)

Comment: Can you share the details of the implementations ? I am having the exact same problem but I am not sure how to go about it ?

Comment: I can't provide code implementation details but the linked tools are very useful in detecting circular dependencies. Try to get rid of such circular dependencies and see if your problem gets resolved.

Comment: I have a side a question about this question: why does circular dependency make no problem while we run the app (whether production or development), but it makes problem while writing unit tests?

Comment: I don't have an exact answer. But a quick guess is that it could be tied to the bundler. When running the app, we use Webpack which might not be concerned about those circular dependencies. Whereas Jest has its own module loading mechanism which hits on this problem. But circular dependency often indicates that code design is not correct or optimal. I'd recommend using relevant ESLint rules for static checks.